# How to get the value of an autoincreament field from SQLiteDatabase in Android?

Tags: android, auto-increment, sqlite

I have a table in `SQLiteDatabase` with only one column which is `autoincreament`...

```
CREATE TABLE [LEADID] (
[lead_id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
 )
```

I want the value of `autoincrement` to start from 10000.
How do i get the value of this column??? 
How do i put an insert and a select statement to get the autoincreamented value??
i basically dont know how to invoke this table to generate this autoincrement value...
how do i do that??

Please help!!! thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set new auto-increment starting value for table `mytable` using this:

```
UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = 10000 WHERE name = 'mytable'
```

If your table already has primary key present with value that conflicts (like 10000), next insert will automatically change auto-increment value to `max_value+1`.

Comment: `sqlite_sequence` is special system table where SQLite keeps track of auto-increment values for all tables. `name` and `seq` are simply columns in that table, which represent table name and its starting autoinc value.

Comment: ok ok! so the my create statement is correct?? do i need to alter my create statement to use this???

Comment: No, you do not need DEFAULT - it will not help you. Instead, run `CREATE TABLE` statement, followed by `UPDATE sqlite_sequence ...` - then it will work the way you want it to.

Comment: this is my create statement `CREATE TABLE [LEADID] (
[lead_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
)`

Comment: i put update statement also...but when i do a select statement i do not get anything

Comment: You have to execute `CREATE TABLE` first, then separately execute `UPDATE sqlite_sequence ...`. After that, attempts to `INSERT` will use auto-inc values starting from 10000 (as long as you do not specify explicit value for primary key).

Comment: but my table has only one value which is an autoincrement ...so wat do i pass in the parameter??...how do i write the insert statement??

Comment: Simply execute `CREATE TABLE leadid (lead_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)`, followed by `UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq = 10000 WHERE name = 'leadid'` - that is all. Any `INSERT` into table `leadid` after that would use 10000, 10001, ... for `lead_id`.